# Primary key index not used when using inner join with jsonb_array_elements subquery on Postgresql 9.5

Tags: postgresql, index, join, json

I have two tables: hub and huboperator

**`hub` table is defined as**

```
CREATE TABLE public.hub
(
  parent_hub_id integer,
  ancestors jsonb,
  descendants jsonb,
  name character varying(1024),
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('hub_id_seq'::regclass),
 ....other fields
)
```

***`huboperator` table is defined as***

```
CREATE TABLE public.huboperator
(   
  employee_id integer NOT NULL, 
  hub_id integer NOT NULL, 
  CONSTRAINT huboperator_pkey 
    PRIMARY KEY (hub_id, employee_id)
)
```

`"descendants"` of `hub` is a jsonb array.

I have defined a hierarchy of hubs in the form of tree using parent_hub_id. All descendants of a hub are stored in the "descendants" array. An employee is assigned to a hub through huboperator table. If an employee is assigned to a hub, they can access that hub with all its descendants. To get the name of all the hubs which can be accessed, I use the following query:

```
SELECT hub.id, hub.name from (SELECT distinct
(jsonb_array_elements(A.descendents || 
jsonb_build_array(A.id))::text)::integer AS id FROM hub A
INNER JOIN huboperator on huboperator.hub_id = A.id 
WHERE huboperator.employee_id = 1321)
AS all_hubs INNER JOIN hub ON hub.id = all_hubs.id
```

The explain analyze result of the query is:

```
Hash Join  (cost=18.18..310.29 rows=100 width=27) (actual time=4.945..46.369 rows=320 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (hub.id = (((jsonb_array_elements((a.descendents || jsonb_build_array(a.id))))::text)::integer))
   ->  Seq Scan on hub  (cost=0.00..254.26 rows=9826 width=27) (actual time=0.010..18.717 rows=9826 loops=1)
   ->  Hash  (cost=16.93..16.93 rows=100 width=4) (actual time=4.913..4.913 rows=320 loops=1)
         Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 20kB
         ->  HashAggregate  (cost=15.41..15.93 rows=100 width=11) (actual time=3.582..4.214 rows=320 loops=1)
               Group Key: ((jsonb_array_elements((a.descendents || jsonb_build_array(a.id))))::text)::integer
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.29..15.16 rows=100 width=11) (actual time=0.391..2.758 rows=320 loops=1)
                     ->  Seq Scan on huboperator  (cost=0.00..6.34 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.013..0.127 rows=1 loops=1)
                           Filter: (employee_id = 1321)
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 346
                     ->  Index Scan using hub_pkey on hub a  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=11) (actual time=0.012..0.017 rows=1 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (id = huboperator.hub_id)
 Planning time: 0.768 ms
 Execution time: 47.206 ms
```

**Why is sequential scan performed on hub.id in the outer inner join?**

If I turn off sequential scan through SET enable_seqscan = false, the analyze output is:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=20.12..472.61 rows=100 width=27) (actual time=2.789..7.873 rows=320 loops=1)
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=19.84..20.36 rows=100 width=11) (actual time=2.756..3.311 rows=320 loops=1)
         Group Key: ((jsonb_array_elements((a.descendents || jsonb_build_array(a.id))))::text)::integer
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.43..19.59 rows=100 width=11) (actual time=0.432..1.988 rows=320 loops=1)
               ->  Index Only Scan using huboperator_pkey on huboperator  (cost=0.15..10.76 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.045..0.048 rows=1 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (employee_id = 1321)
                     Heap Fetches: 0
               ->  Index Scan using hub_pkey on hub a  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=11) (actual time=0.018..0.023 rows=1 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (id = huboperator.hub_id)
   ->  Index Scan using hub_pkey on hub  (cost=0.29..4.50 rows=1 width=27) (actual time=0.005..0.007 rows=1 loops=320)
         Index Cond: (id = (((jsonb_array_elements((a.descendents || jsonb_build_array(a.id))))::text)::integer))
 Planning time: 0.735 ms
 Execution time: 8.562 ms
```

**Is there a way to use sequential scan in the query without turning off enable_seqscan? Can the query be restructured to make it faster?**

Comment: Are these example reproducible?  That is, If you run each query multiple times in a row, does the timing change?